# Building Cmake on AIX does not succeed?

Tags: cmake, aix

I'm trying to reproduce an issue reported on AIX. I need to install CMake in `$HOME` because the machine lacks CMake and I am not an admin on the machine. The machine is [GCC119 on the compile farm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/CompileFarm). GCC119 is ppc64-be, if it matters.

I downloaded CMake 3.11 and unpacked into `$HOME/cmake-3.11/`. According to the `README.rst`:

> UNIX/Mac OSX/MinGW/MSYS/Cygwin
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> You need to have a C++ compiler (supporting C++11) and a `make`
>   installed. Run the `bootstrap` script you find in the source
>   directory of CMake. You can use the `--help` option to see the
>   supported options. You may use the `--prefix=<install_prefix>`
>   option to specify a custom installation directory for CMake. You can
>   run the `bootstrap` script from within the CMake source directory or
>   any other build directory of your choice. Once this has finished
>   successfully, run `make` and `make install`.  In summary::
>
> ```
> $ ./bootstrap && make && make install
> ```

It seems fairly straight forward:

```
-bash-4.4$ CXX=g++ ./bootstrap --prefix=$HOME
---------------------------------------------
CMake 3.11.4, Copyright 2000-2018 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
C compiler on this system is: gcc   -pthread
C++ compiler on this system is: g++   -pthread
Makefile processor on this system is: gmake
-bash-4.4$ gmake
gmake: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
-bash-4.4$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
-bash-4.4$ find . -name Makefile
-bash-4.4$ find . -name makefile
-bash-4.4$ find . -name cmake
./Auxiliary/bash-completion/cmake
```

It looks like things did not succeed but I am not sure what went wrong or how to proceed. There does not appear to be a log file, either:

```
-bash-4.4$ ls *.log
ls: 0653-341 The file *.log does not exist.
```

What are my next steps?

---

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 7.2.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: very few AIX people here on S.O. (but you might luck out!). I've seen good answers in AIX section of https://toolbox.com and there used to be good support on the IBM user forums . Where I used AIX, getting anything installed was a 6 month project, so I'd try to write up my own solution as code ;-/ . YRMV. Good luck.

Comment: As a start, add option `--verbose` to `bootstrap`

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be several problems. First, Cmake cannot use IBM XLC. When it tries to use XLC bootstrap selects options it can't handle so it dies.

Second, working around the issue:

```
CC=gcc CXX=g++ ./bootstrap --prefix="$HOME/cmake"
```

Results in:

```
$ CC=gcc CXX=g++ bash -x ./bootstrap --prefix="$HOME/cmake"
++ uname
+ cmake_system=AIX
+++ dirname ./bootstrap
++ cd .
++ pwd
+ cmake_source_dir=/home/noloader/build-llvm/cmake_build
...

+ gmake
g++   -pthread -I/home/noloader/build-llvm/cmake_build/Bootstrap.cmk \
 -I/home/noloader/build-llvm/cmake_build/Source \
 -I/home/noloader/build-llvm/cmake_build/Source/LexerParser \
 -I/home/noloader/build-llvm/cmake_build/Utilities \
 -c /home/noloader/build-llvm/cmake_build/Source/cmAddCustomCommandCommand.cxx-o \
 cmAddCustomCommandCommand.o
In file included from /home/noloader/build-llvm/cmake_build/Source/cmTarget.h:16:0,
                 from /home/noloader/build-llvm/cmake_build/Source/cmGlobalGenerator.h:21,
                 from /home/noloader/build-llvm/cmake_build/Source/cmAddCustomCommandCommand.cxx:11:
/home/noloader/build-llvm/cmake_build/Source/cmAlgorithms.h:8:10:
fatal error: cm_kwiml.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cm_kwiml.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'cmAddCustomCommandCommand.o' failed
gmake: *** [cmAddCustomCommandCommand.o] Error 1
+ RES=2
+ '[' 2 -ne 0 ']'
+ cmake_error 9 'Problem while running gmake'
+ res=9
+ shift 1
```

The problem here is, there is no file `cm_kwiml.h`:

```
$ pwd
/home/noloader/build-llvm/cmake_build

$ find . -name "cm_kwiml.h"
$
```

I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Download the source ( https://cmake.org/files/v3.11/cmake-3.11.4.tar.gz ), and you will find `cmake-3.11.4/Utilities/cm_kwiml.h`

Comment: FWIW, I have **used** CMake (successfully, obviously) on AIX / XLC... but that has been two years ago, and I no longer have access to the AIX machine. The artifacts are still in [my build framework](https://rootdirectory.ddns.net/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=JAWS&path=%2Fcmake%2FCheckAIXEnvironment.cmake). So if CMake no longer works on AIX, that's a regression.

Comment: The issues with using IBM XL C/C++ for AIX to build CMake are being discussed [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18460).

Comment: @DevSolar - Request an account at the [GCC Compile Farm](https://cfarm.tetaneutral.net/). They have 8 PowerPC machines. GCC111 is AIX with POWER7, and GCC119 is AIX with POWER8. Or, email me at *noloader*, gmail account with your SSH keys. I will temporarily add you to my account.